# Any way to unfriend with the Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to be able to authenticate then list out all my friends and have the ability to unfriend someone without going through the process on the website.

Is there any way to do that using their SDK in-app with a dialog or to jump to their app only to approve.. any workaround??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for removing friends or deleting content (other than content uploaded by the same app)

Comment: I saw that on the web, but is there any workaround, let's say to open the Facebook App with the given friend to confirm the Unfriend?